# Would the basic design of a service using a repository and interfaces be the same in Scala?

Tags: scala, soa

When designing a service, I normally do the following in java:

```
interface UserService {

}

public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

}
```

And my UserServiceImpl would use Repositories like:

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

   @Autowired
   private IUserRepository userRepository;

}
```

I use spring or guice for depedancy injection.

How with Scala, would I follow the same pattern or is it common to do things differently?

Comment: Use the Cake Pattern. I've learned to love it.

Comment: Typeclasses and implicit parameters provide another way of doing DI directly in Scala. The pros & cons of this vs the layer cake (and other approaches) depend on the structure of your project. How many and what kinds of services and repositories are there? What is the logic behind choosing a specific repository for a service?

Comment: The following article compares some of the way of doing DI in scala, including layer cakes and implicits. http://jonasboner.com/2008/10/06/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/

Answer (score 1):

For such thing in Scala Cake pattern exists. You can abstract over your repository type in a trait, e.g:

```
trait RepositoryModule {
  type Repository <: RepositoryLike

  val userRepository: Repository

  trait RepositoryLike { 
    // some definitions and implementation
  }
}
```

Later you can make concrete versions of this repo module, for example in memory version for tests and real version for some real repo, e.g:

```
trait InMemoRepoModule extends RepositoryModule {
  trait Repository extends RepositoryLike {
    // here comes module implementation
  }
}
```

Later, or as it's called "at the end of the world", you can mix this implementation:

```
class ServiceStack extends InMemoRepoModule {
  object userRepository extends Repository
}
```

And this is a great abstraction mechanism, cause later you can abstract even further using type-constructors, this is a great way to use monads:

```
trait RepositoryModule[M[+_]] {
  type Repository <: RepositoryLike

  implicit val M: scalaz.Monad[M]

  val userRepository: Repository

  trait RepositoryLike { 
    def getAllusers(): M[List[User]]
  }
}
```

Now you change the way you are processing data by changing the monad, i.e if in production you want async execution then use `Future`, but in tests you need synchronous execution, then you can use `Id` monad from scalaz, or if you want to check exceptions then use `Either`:

```
trait RemoteRepoModule extends RepositoryModule[Future] {
  trait Repository extends RepositoryLike {
     def getAllUsers(): Future[List[User]] = Future {
       // just implement this module
     }
   }
}
```

If you want a practical example how to do this, take a look at [this](https://github.com/slamdata/platform) project on github. And [this](https://github.com/slamdata/platform/blob/master/mimir/src/main/scala/com/precog/mimir/Evaluator.scala#L68) example of such an injection mechanism

Comment: wow thanks.  Is that your pic, you look like you are 15 years old!